# How shoud I interpret a 'breach letter' in this case?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Let's assume there was a car accident, specifically on the bus ride so it's not your fault, and you received a letter below. (Idk who is the sender, only that it is related to the accident)  What does the breach letter mean in this case? 
I searched the meaning of a breach letter and it says it is 'a letter sent before accelerating the loan and proceeding with foreclosure'. But.. in this case, it doesn't make sense to me;

+edit : Oh, I'm not the recipient of the letter so I can't read what this 'attached' breach letter says. Someone asked about this case and I also got curious about what the breach letter is supposed to mean here in this context :]

Please see the attached *breach letter*.
If you could please contact me at your earliest convenience on 0001-000-1111 to discuss your claim that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [*Many of the deeds that were used at the bank required a **30 day certified letter notification**. This is usually referred to as a **breach letter**.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+deeds+that+were+used+at+the+bank%22) Or you could just Google "define breach letter" - for which the first result is a detailed definition. It's just the first (formal) stage in a legal process, whether relating to an insurance claim or a mortgage default. But since the breach letter is *attached*, why can't you just read it to see what it means?

Comment: Breach of duty-of-care ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "breach" is the act of breaking or failing to observe a law, agreement, or a deadline.

I can only assume that a "breach letter" or "breach notification" is a letter notifying you that a breach of some kind has occurred.

Given the context, the 'breach' could refer to:

- the breach of some traffic law
- the breach of a deadline stated in a previous letter - perhaps because you did not respond by a stated deadline?

I would hope that it would become apparent by reading the attached breach letter.